# Is it possible to automatically turn vibrate mode off at night?

Tags: iphone, notifications, vibrate

I usually have my iPhone in "vibrate mode" (ringtone off, vibrate on). However, I'd like to additionally have it turn vibrate mode off automatically between for example 11 PM and 7 AM because I don't want to be awakened (or have my wife woken up) by some spam mail that arrives at 2 AM.

Some apps allow to define periods where notifications are suppressed, but it seems the Notification center (or at least the Mail app) does not. Is there any way to achieve this (on a non-jailbroken iPhone)?

I know I can turn it off manually in Preferences, but that's cumbersome, and I'm going to forget either to turn it off or to turn it back on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## EDIT:

This is a feature in iOS 6. You can schedule notification suppression by opening the Settings app > Notifications > Do not disturb.

#### Original Post:

Unfortunately, there is no native way to do that in iOS 5.

Like you thought, the notification center, currently does not allow customization in that way. I think Apple could have added features similar to that one, but have chosen not to, either because they haven't wanted to take the time (but that hasn't seemed to stop them in the past), or because they have a big focus on keeping things simple.

Comment: You were right about iOS 6: http://www.apple.com/ios/ios6/. By the way, sorry I had somehow forgotten to upvote your answer the first time around - better late than never.

Comment: That's pretty cool. I'll try to remember to update my answer when iOS 6 is released. Thanks for the vote.

Comment: Hey, I've just installed iOS 6 - it works fine. Interestingly (and sensibly), it only suppresses sounds and vibration if the phone is sleeping at the moment; if it's turned on, notifications will occur just as they would if Do Not Disturb was switched off.

Comment: That is very interesting indeed. Hopefully that will work out well for you.

Comment: I have a slightly different problem. I'm like you during the day but at night, vibration doesn't wake me up. That's a problem if I am called by a Favorites or a Repeated Call at night during my Do Not Disturb time. Any way for these to produce ringtones even if phone is left in silent with vibrate on?

Comment: @jwco, as far as I'm concerned, the vibrate switch is never overridden with a phone call. The Clock app's alarm, and some other alarm apps do ring regardless of the vibrate switch. So I believe you would need to disable vibrate.